# Is it possible to export default arrow function with just one line in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, export

```
const func: () => void = () => {
    console.log('I CAN export my function in this way');
};

export default func;
```

```
export default () => void = () => {
    console.log('I CANNOT export my function in this way (Parsing error: Expression expected.)');
};
```

As above code shown, we can always declare and assign a function in both ways. However, I cannot export the arrow fucntion with same syntax by `export default`. How come?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't export something as default with a type annotation on the same line. If you wanted to do it in a one-liner while retaining the function signature you could do it as a named export:

```
   export const func: () => void = () => {
        console.log('I CAN export my function in this way');
    };
```

the importing file would then import like this:

```
import {func} from 'path'
```

or...

You'd have to rip off the function signature:

```
export default () => {
    console.log('I CAN export my function in this way')
}
```

Then import it as whatever:

```
`import bloopityBloop from 'path'`
```

Comment: If I rip off the function signature, I can't pass eslint: `Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)`

Comment: You have a choice to make. You can add `// @ts-ignore` to bypass the linter for that export, or use an export method that allows you to retain the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

You sure *can* export default and apply a type/interface in one statement...

```
export default (
  () => {
    console.log('I CAN export my function in this way');
  }
) as () => void;
```